# css :before content spacing

Tags: css

Using CSS to create a horizontal navigation I want to use a divider between the elements.

using:

```
li:before
{
  content: " | ";
}
```

I get a divider. But i wanna use a margin between the text and the divider

> item(margin-right) |(?)item(margin-right)

how can I set a margin to the above question mark? With a margin-left (or padding-left) the margin will exist in front of the divider, not between the divider and the content.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As a quick hack, you can add a non-breaking space by using the escaped unicode for it:

```
li:before {
  content: "\00a0 | \00a0";
}​
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uMFHH/).

But the better solution is to set a margin-left AND margin-right (or padding) for the pseudo element:

```
li:before {
  content: "|";
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F94hC/1/).

Comment: @doublejosh still working fine over here. What exactly is not working for you? Check out the fiddle under my last code block

Comment: Whops! I had a stray comment killing my rule.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
li:before {
          content: "|";
          padding:0 5px;
        }
```